# UIView background sizing issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview

I'm adding a UIImageView to the UIViewController's UIView as I would normally, with the frame of the image view being the same as `self.view` to make sure that the image will cover the whole view. However, there is a roughly 20px padding between the status bar and the imageView which I can't seem to get rid of.

I've tried NSLogging the different frames, and receiving the following results:

```
 NSLog(@"ImageView => %@", NSStringFromCGRect([imageView frame]));
 NSLog(@"self.view => %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));
 NSLog(@"Screen Bounds => %@", NSStringFromCGRect([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]));
 NSLog(@"App window => %@", NSStringFromCGRect([[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] frame]));

[LaunchViewController.m: line 26] ImageView => {{0, 0}, {320, 548}} 
[LaunchViewController.m: line 27] self.view => {{0, 0}, {320, 548}} 
[LaunchViewController.m: line 28] Screen Bounds => {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}   
[LaunchViewController.m: line 29] App window => {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}
```

The results show that the image view should in fact be covering `self.view` with no padding at all between itself and the status bar.

The UIViewController is the root view controller of a UINavigationController, and I have set the navigation bar to be hidden. I thought that maybe this could be causing the issue however, after removing the UINavigationController and replacing it with just the UIViewController, the padding was still there.

Has anybody got any advice for removing the padding / has experience this issue before and has a fix?

Here is an image showing what's going on - the green area is the UIView (`self.view`), and the orange area is the UIImageView.

[image]

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Orange-568h@2x.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: are you doing this on viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear?

Comment: -viewDidLoad - before calling super.

Comment: try moving it to viewDidAppear, on viewDidLoad, if you are using a xib, view size is based on the xib's view.

Comment: at least try moving your nslog's to the viewDidAppear. You should detect a change.

Comment: The NSLogs showed that there is in fact a 20px difference between the frame of the mainScreen and the self.view

Comment: this means your xib and your current view has a change, that appears between viewDidAppear and viewDidLoad

Comment: Maybe this is not the problem but if you're using XIBs take a look at the Status Bar tab in Simulated Metrics of IB. Try to set it to None.

Comment: @mat I'm not actually using a nib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app delegate set the FullScreenLayout to YES just before you make it the view controller the root view controller:

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[vc setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];
[[self window] setRootViewController:vc];
```

or you can set it in viewDidLoad

```
[self setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];
```

A summary on setWantsFullScreenLayout:
When a view controller presents its view, it normally shrinks that view so that its frame does not overlap the device’s status bar. Setting this property to YES causes the view controller to size its view so that it fills the entire screen, including the area under the status bar. (Of course, for this to happen, the window hosting the view controller must itself be sized to fill the entire screen, including the area underneath the status bar.) You would typically set this property to YES in cases where you have a translucent status bar and want your view’s content to be visible behind that view. From [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it solved with this:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

`self.view.frame` give you the wrong `x` and `y` when status bar is not `hidden`

Comment: If you have a look at the code I posted, you'll find that the frame is exactly the same as that.

Comment: self.view.frame give you the wrong x and y when status bar is not hidden, try it and see

Answer (score 1):

See your `self.view`, it is 20 points below, as the status bar is shown.
hence, the `self.view.frame` is `(0,20,w,h)`

your image view takes the same rect `(0,20,w,h)` and adds it to `self.view`. With respect to `self.view` the image view sets its frame to 20 points below the "y" position of `self.view`.

Try setting `self.view.bounds` to the image view frame.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try UIImageView `*imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];` isntead. Using `bounds` instead of `frame`

Comment: Try not setting the image and instead set the backgroundColour of your imageView so you can be sure about the frame that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

on the `viewDidLoad` method  your UIViewController's xib is loaded and your updated values regarding your User Interface is not detected.

This causes no trouble if your UIView is exactly same (no UINavigationBar, UITabbar, status bar or device -iPhone 3.5 inch / 4 inch change). But if you are changing anything in the process, you might get false values on `viewDidLoad`.

Easiest way to check this is to debug your screen and view bounds on the viewDidAppear, after UI gets updated.

Please check your xib/storyboard. There is a change between your current UI and designed interface.

To solve this you might use a function `updateUI` on the `viewDidAppear` and update related view's again.

```
[self.imageView setFrame:self.view.frame]
```

this will fix it.

Comment: I'm not using a nib or storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try move [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES]; to

```
- (void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear: animated];    

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden: YES
                                             animated: NO];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to change self.view.frame to self.view.bounce when you add imageView into self.view.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
```

Or just use CGRectMake(0,0,320,568)

Comment: It needs to be dynamic I'm afraid. The app will not only be running on the iPhone 5.

Comment: this is forcing a CGRect, not a solution. I am sure OP could have figured it out all by himself. Yet he is seeking why is this happening

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054539/not-sure-why-uiview-is-being-nudged-up-by-around-10px