# UIView's frame origin.y = 0 but displayed at origin.y = statusBarHeight

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

i have a main view containing 3 subviews and i have a strange behaviour with the last one.
I set its frame origin to 0,0 and it appears 20px under the statusBar. To fix the problem i have to set frame.origin.y = -20 . How is it possible? The 2 other views are correctly shown...

Answer (score 0):

How is the problematic view constructed? If it comes from a nib or a storyboard, have a look at the 'simulated metrics' for the appropriate item -- you may have a status bar enabled the view in question. If so, try setting 'None' for the status bar.

Comment: Yes its loaded from a nib but i already tried to remove the simulated metrics but nothing changed...

Comment: I noted one difference thought, the view is a navigationController.view, if i remove the navController and just add its rootViewController directly to self.view, i don't have the Y origin glitch

Comment: Found the answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041060/iphone-weird-space-at-the-top-of-uinavigationcontroller

Comment: Just put navController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;